# How to get Related fields in conga composer

Tags: conga-composer

I have installed conga composer 8 and created button in Opportunities tab but when I open Conga ,related fields are not showing in any tab.
So how do I get the related fields or where can I find it ?

Answer (score 2):

Conga Composer will provide Opportunity, Account, and Product Line Items by default on the Opportunity object.  If you need information from related objects, I would encourage you to use Conga Queries to gather that information.  With Queries, you can access fields from any related object(s).

Steps
 1. Create a new record in Conga Query object
 2. add the query via Conga Query Builder (or from any self generated SOQL tool like Workbench or Data Loader)
 3. Reference the QueryId in the Conga Button URL
 4. Construct your template using the appropriate references from the template builder.

There is exhaustive documentation on the site: [support.getconga.com](http://support.getconga.com) also the support team is pretty awesome so don't hesitate to throw a case over for assistance.